# Library adapter performance loss

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, adapter, wrapper, eigen3

I am trying to wrap the Eigen3 linear algebra library so that its syntax becomes cleaner. However as a first step, when I am creating the + operator overload (through += overload), the wrapper immediately suffers from a 3 time performance loss. Could you please provide some insights about where did things go wrong and how to fix? Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
#include "Eigen\Eigen"

class Wmat
{
    Eigen::ArrayXXd M;
public:
    Wmat& operator+=(const Wmat& rhs)
        {this->M += rhs.M; return *this;}
    const Wmat operator+(const Wmat &rhs2)
        {Wmat result = *this; result+= rhs2; return result;}
    void Random(int D1, int D2)
        {M = Eigen::ArrayXXd::Random(D1,D2);}
};

int main()
{
    int D = 1000000;
    int T=1000;
    clock_t start;
//---------------------------------------------------------------
    Eigen::ArrayXXd LHS = Eigen::ArrayXXd::Random(D,1);
    Eigen::ArrayXXd RHS1 = Eigen::ArrayXXd::Random(D,1);
    Eigen::ArrayXXd RHS2 = Eigen::ArrayXXd::Random(D,1);
    start = clock();
    for (int i=1; i<=T; ++i)
    {
        LHS = RHS1 + RHS2;
    }
    cout << (clock()-start) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
//---------------------------------------------------------------
    Wmat LHSW, RHSW1, RHSW2;
    RHSW1.Random(D,1); RHSW2.Random(D,1); LHSW.Random(D,1);
    start = clock();
    for (int i=1; i<=T; ++i)
    {
        LHSW = RHSW1 + RHSW2;
    }
    cout << (clock()-start) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
//---------------------------------------------------------------
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you timing an optimized build, or an unoptimized "debug" build?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, I am running both direct Eigen3 and wrapped Eigen3 under the release build. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the Eigen library is simply much better at avoiding copying? For example, `RHSW1 + RHSW2` doesn't actually have to create a new matrix, it only needs to create an object that stores references to the two operands and, when assigned to a matrix, that evaluates the expression and stores it in the target. This technique can give a big speedup. That said, use a profiler to find out where the time is spent. Also, consider the possibility that the Eigen developers compromised on readability for performance.

Comment: Thanks @UlrichEckhardt ! I created a plus function to avoid allocation and it does bring the performance much closer. I am quite sure you caught the difference. Does this mean I should wrap the class with pointer operations rather than holding ArrayXXd as members?

Comment: After looking at Eigen a bit, I really wonder what syntax you take offence at so that you think that a wrapper makes it better? If typing `Eigen::ArrayXXd` is too much for you, use a `typedef` or a using declaration to shorten the name. Also, I can now confirm that they are doing lots of advanced C++ template trickery, probably to improve the syntax while retaining good performance.

Comment: I am trying to adapt the interface so that I can swap Eigen3 into some pre-existing programs.

Answer (score 1):

Writing a wrapper won't work with expression templates. For instance, any method you add in `Wmat` won't be available for `a+b` unless you explicitly evaluate it within a `Wmat` thus loosing much of the power of Eigen. The right approach to make it comptable with an old matrix/vector library is to exploit Eigen's plugin mechanism. This mechanism allows to add new members directly inside the class definition of Eigen's objects and expressions. See this [page](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicCustomizingEigen.html) for the details.